# How to check if a user is logged in and if not redirect to the login screen

Tags: ios, swift2

I have my login screen embedded in a `UINavigationController` and my home page screen embedded in a `UITabBarController`.

My login page was done programmatically and `TabBarController` was created using `storyboards`. In `AppDelegate.swift` file I made the the login screen the `rootViewController`.

But now I want to check if the user is logged in and make the `TabBarController` the `rootViewController`, and if the user isn't logged in, redirect to the login screen, then segue to the `TabBarController` and make it the `rootViewController`.

The server authenticates the user by sending a **token** to the client. Do I store the token using `NSUserDefaults`? Should I check if the user has `_token`_ as a way to validate if the user is logged in?

Comment: That's a way commonly used to validate if the user is logged in. Just like cookies are used in web development.

Comment: @Adeel do i do the check in viewWillAppear in every UIVewController class and also in AppDelegate when i call the app the first time?

Comment: No, not in _viewWillAppear_ in fact not in any of the view controllers. You need to check for the token in _didFinishLanchingWithOption_ method of your _AppDelegate_.

Comment: @Adeel ok but wont that check it only once when the app loads?

Comment: You are right and that's the only place where you need to check and set your _rootViewController_. Because every time the application is launched, initially the _rootViewController_ is what you have set in the storyboard and that's the point when you need to decide if the users is already logged in or not. Otherwise the app works as expected. If you have a specific scenario in your mind then tell me.

Comment: @Adeel ok since i programmatically created the login page, i made it the rootview controller initally. But now i have created a Tab controller with storyboards. Do i check in didFinishLaunchingWithOption for the token, if the user has a token set the TabController as the rootviewController, and if not set the rootviewController to the login page and after the user signs in then set the tabcontroller to be the rootview controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127019/discussion-between-user3497437-and-adeel).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are creating your `LoginViewController` programatically so I assume that the `TabBarController` would be the `rootViewController` of the `storyboard` by default. All you need to do in your `AppDelegate` is this.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let token = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "token")
    if token == nil {
        //***************
        //Create your LoginViewController and make it the rootViewController
        //***************
    }
    return true
}
```

Note: I'm using `Swift 3` so there will be a slight difference in the syntax.

Comment: thanks also when the user has signed from the login screen, should i dismiss the login screen controller and initailize the tabcontroller  as the rootview controller

Comment: yes that's right. You just need to `instantiate` the `TabBarController` and set it as the `rootViewController` of your application's key window. And remember, never push/present a `TabBarController` on to another `ViewController`.

Comment: thanks. So i dismiss the navigation controller and set the rootviewcontroller to tab controller

Comment: yeah that's it.

Comment: also forgot to mention when the user ever signs out of the app, do i clear or delete the token?

Comment: yes that's very important otherwise it'll lead to a very unexpected behaviour of the application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127020/discussion-between-user3497437-and-adeel).